# Describe all one-dimensional representations of the alternating group A4.

Tags: representation-theory

Describe all one-dimensional representations of the alternating group A4. I think I  may need to find the commutator subgroup of A4. Now the commutator subgroup of $A_4$ is $H=\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$.

Now can anyone help me? What to do next?

Answer (score 2):

The group $A_4$ has order 12, and its commutator subgroup $H$ has order 4.  So, the quotient $A_4/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.  The one-dimensional representations of $A_4$ are precisely the irreducible representations of the quotient group, identified as functions on $A_4$ by the rule $\chi(g) = \tilde{\chi}(gH)$, where $\tilde{\chi}$ is an irreducible representation of the quotient.  So now, your problem is reduced to finding the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.  One is the trivial character.  Another takes the generator of the quotient to a primitive 3rd root of unity, and the third is the complex conjugate of the second.

Answer (score 2):

$A_4'\simeq V_4$ then $A_4'/V_4 \simeq Z_3$. It is well known (and easy to prove) that all one-dimensional representations of a group G (over algebraically closed field) can be obtained us one-dimensional representations of G/G'. So you just ought to construct all one-dimensional representations of $Z_3.$